# Spring cloud ingestion layer (API Gateway for protocol transformations)

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-stream

I am looking for an open source API Gateway that can do protocol transformations (Spring Cloud offers Zuul but it accepts only REST connections and does not do protocol transformations). Any idea (or clever solution) given that most of the following protocols must be supported?

1. CoAP
2. AMQP
3. MQTT (must be supported)
4. STOMP
5. REST (must be supported)

Sine the next hop after the API Gateway, I was thinking Spring Cloud Stream with custom inbound/outbound adapters. There is also the Spring Cloud Data Flow but I think that is it a different beast.

PS: Oracle API Gateway seems to support multiple protocols but I am looking for an open source solution.

Comment: Have you looked at [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org)

Comment: I don`t know what you looking for. But you can look at Apache Camel

Comment: Apache Camel is not an API Gateway.